# IllegalStateExeption Another SimpleCache Instance uses the folder after using single kotlin android

Tags: kotlin, singleton, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I am getting Error **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another SimpleCache instance uses the folder:"** I am working with SimpleExoPlayer and this error shows when I create a single instance of simplecache.

Logic

```
single<Cahce> {
 SimpleCache(File(""), evictor, dbProvider)
}
```